# Help with permissions for a folder on another hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive

I have three hard drives, when I installed 16.04.2, I manually setup the drives where the swap and `/` partitions are on `/dev/sda1`, `/data` is on `/dev/sdb1`, and `/backup` is on `/dev/sdc1` as a primary partition.  Each hard drive is 1TB.  The file `/etc/fstab` accurately reflects this.  I plan to use `/data` to hold data and VM's.  My problem is with folder permissions.  It says root has access, but I do not.

I am confused on how I should go about setting up permissions for myself and no one else.

Comment: could you post the output of `ls -l /`?

Comment: you're talking about permissions on  `/data`, right? Please could you post the contents of your fstab or output of something like `mount  | grep /dev/sdb1` so we can see the mount options and fs type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to /data and /backup.

`sudo chown [yourUser]:[yourGroup] /data /backup`

That's all there is to it. Root has always access to everything. Since you just installed all root mounts are owned by root.

You can also solve it differently and add a folder in each of those mounts. 
After that you adjust the rights of those folders to your user. Both solutions would work.

```
sudo mkdir /data/mydata /backup/mybackup
sudo chown [yourUser]:[yourGroup] /data/mydata /backup/mybackup
```